# jQuery plugin like Dolphin file browser (KDE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kde-plasma

Is any plugin works like Dolphin file manager (Columns mode) for jQuery?

[View Full Size Image (1366x718)](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/7531/screenshotlibevent004do.png)
[Dolphin Browser http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/7531/screenshotlibevent004do.png](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/7531/screenshotlibevent004do.png)

Comment: Also to note you need to expand your question. e.g. what is your data source? what are you browsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw some jquery plugins for file manager.

1. [jQuery File Tree](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree) - [Demo](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/fileTree/demo/)
2. [columnview](http://www.christianyates.com/blog/jquery/finder-column-view-hierarchical-lists-jquery) - [Demo](http://static.christianyates.com/columnview/demo.html)
3. [jQuery Column List View](http://code.google.com/p/jcvl/) - [Demo](http://knell.ho.ua/jcvl/)

I hope you to help.